# Changing the default view for set regarding look when open from outlook client crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Our client has a requirement that whenever some one opens up the set regarding look-up from the ribbon on  a meeting it should open up the client look up showing only active clients.Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: you only want to show active clients record in some lookup fields? can you modify the filter view on those lookup fields?

Comment: Jeff - Set regarding look up opens directly from the crm 2011 outlook add-in and we have no control over the requests it makes to open the look up view.Right now it opens up the look up view showing all the client by default.